# Bash script access redirected|piped input

Tags: linux, bash

I found a nice utility script which efficiently outputs a desired number of lines from a desired start line. I have named it mid.bak and it is based on a post here >> http://www.fastechws.com/tricks/unix/head_tail_mid_files.php

Usage: mid.bak startline numlines filename

```
$ cat mid.bak
#!/bin/sh
echo "Positional parameter count: $#"
tail -n +$1 $3 | head -n $2
echo "Parameter three is: $3"
```

Case I: per the normal usage outlined above, positional parameter "$3" is found.

```
$ mid.bak 3 2 file.txt
Positional parameter count: 3
This line 3 in file.txt
This line 4 in file.txt
Parameter three is: file.txt
```

Cases II & III : "$3" is mysteriously absent.

```
$ mid.bak 3 2 < file.txt
Positional parameter count: 2
This line 3 in file.txt
This line 4 in file.txt
Parameter three is: 

$ cat file.txt | mid.bak 3 2
Positional parameter count: 2
This line 3 in file.txt
This line 4 in file.txt
Parameter three is:
```

My question: Positional parameter $3 above is available to the script by the normal $1, $2 .. reference for Case I. So why it is not included in the count "$#" & not echoing out for cases II & III?

Comment: Because there are only two arguments to your program in cases 2 and 3. Try adding another argument after `3 2` and see what it prints out

Comment: Thank you Hunter. But notice that $3 is in fact available and used just the same in EVERY case: tail -n +$1 $3 .. ah, the script used $3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case I, the name of the file is the 3rd parameter. In cases II and III, there is no 3rd parameter, so `$3` expands to the empty string and, as it isn't quoted, is removed from the list of parameters passed to `tail`. `tail`, not receiving a file name in its argument list, reads instead from standard input, which is connected to `file.txt` via the `<` operator in case II and to the output of `cat file.txt` via a pipeline in case III.

Comment: Thank you chepner. I am working up a more elaborate script along these lines and I understand this parameter delema now. :)